# Vim 'gF' command don't capture python traceback messages line number

Tags: python, vim

"gF" command in VIM edit the file whose name is under or after the cursor, and if a number follows the filename, then the cursor is positioned on that line in the file.

This command finds filename if the characters is in `'isfname'` options value, and find line number follows the filename string. EX.`eval.c @ 20` finds the filename `eval.c` and the line number `20`.
But python traceback message, the file line number is following `'line'`, so the line number couldn't be found.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\gd\jupyter\doc.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(qqq)
```

Howto config vim to let 'gF' command understand python traceback messages?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in `:help gF`, Vim has a special case for:

```
filename line 51
```

It won't work, here, because the filename is both quoted and followed by a comma so it's really the whole `", line`  that is causing issues.

But why are you editing a Python traceback to begin with? Can't you use `:help :make`?

--- EDIT ---

Anyway… having a single use case makes it simpler for you to write your own custom `gF` than for Vim to have a universal solution that can handle all possible cases.

Here is a quick and dirty way to handle this specific use case:

```
function! CustomgF()
    " are we in a terminal window?
    if win_getid()->getwininfo()->get(0, {})->get('terminal', 0)

        " if we are, find a suitable line number on this line
        let line = getline('.')->matchstr(', line \zs\d\+')

        if line
            " if we have one, do regular gF, which won't jump
            " to the desired line anyway because Vim can't parse
            " tracebacks properly
            normal! gF

            " but we don't care because we can jump
            " to the found line on our own
            execute line
        else
            " if we don't, do regular gF
            normal! gF
        endif
    else
        " if we aren't, do regular gF
        normal! gF
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap gF <Cmd>call CustomgF()<CR>
```

The mapping above overrides regular `gF` globally but it only deviates in behaviour:

- in terminal windows,
- *and* if there is a `, line <number>` on the current line.

Comment: A typical scenario for me is that I might have a terminal window open (`:terminal`) in which I run Python code, among other things. If I encounter an error, I switch to Terminal-Normal mode with `CTRL-W N`, move the cursor on the file name and do `gF`. Unfortunately the line number is ignored, for the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I use ```:below :term cmd /c %``` to run Python code in the below terminal window to see complete trace message.

Comment: gF-python-traceback is packaged as a plugin [here](https://github.com/sychen52/gF-python-traceback).